# IE6 throws mix-content warning when using JQuery RTE

Tags: jquery, rich-text-editor

I am using Jquery Rich Text Editor (RTE) in a page accessed through HTTPS in IE6 browser. When the RTE loads I get a mixed-content warning saying:

'This page contains both secure and non secure items. Do you want to display the non secure item ?'

This is probably happening because jquery while creating the RTE creates IFRAMES which have no 'src' attribute defined. This is making IE 6 produce this mix-content warning message.

Can anyone let me know a work around so that this mix-content warning message is not produced?

Thanks

Comment: The only "workaround" I know of is to create those iframes with "src" attributes that refer to an empty page you serve up from your https site. (Maybe it doesn't have to be *your* https site ...)

Comment: @pointy JQuery internally converts the textarea into RTE. I have no control over iframes created by JQuery.

Comment: yes you have control, it's the DOM, you can access and modify to it using jQuery

Comment: @Eduardo Jquery converts the textarea into RTE. As soon as JQuery creates the iframe (without the src attribute), IE6 throws the mix-content warning. So, even though I have control over the DOM, I can't actually prevent the warning pop-up from showing up. Hope, this puts things into a better prespetive

Answer (score 0):

Try using the network tab of Firebug to check if there are library references using HTTP. Maybe it has harcoded image references.

If the "no src" is the problem I'd try to set it to a blank.html file using jQuery after the Rich Text Editor is loaded.

Comment: I agree with the surmise of @aneez: it's definitely the case that `<iframe>` elements without a "src" cause that warning in IE6. I don't think `<img>` tags ever cause the problem, but I could be wrong about that.

Comment: I did check for any requests being made over HTTP and could fine none. While debugging I figured out that the mixed-content warning is thrown when I convert a textarea to RTE using JQuery.

Comment: try $('iframe').attr('src', 'blank.html') after initializing the RTE

Comment: I edited the jquery.rte.js file. I added the code to add the 'src' attribute for the iframe with the value pointing to a blank file retrieved over HTTPS. There are other values like 'javascript:false', 'https:javascript:false', '//0' which one could use, but it didn't work for me.